# Magento does not show Special Price in Cart and Checkout but everywhere else

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I checked my problem on google and also on stackexchange but could not find any solutions.

Basically this magento function is what I am using to get Price in Cart and also in Checkout from the quote Item.

```
     <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
```

This always returns me the original price. In Catalog view in Product Page and in all other places special price is shown properly but not in cart and checkout.

Also totals are calculated based on original price, special price is not taken at there too.

How can I solve this issue with Magento?

Cheers

Comment: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-actual-price-and-special-price-of-a-product/

Comment: $_item->getCalculationPrice() to $_item->getPrice()

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_product->getFinalPrice()` which returns the price including any reductions etc.

If you want the special price as entered in the backend `special price` field use `$_product->getSpecialPrice()`

To see if the product has a special price use the following code.

```
$specialPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
$normalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
if ($normalPrice != $specialPrice)
{
   // has special price
}
```

Comment: I did that already and it is ok but when I do it like that I have to change every price related part with that . In system it is used as getCalculationPrice always. I traced getCalculationPrice function and it goes to hasCustomPrice at the end. But in no where there is a check for SpecialPrice value. On ITEM object in checkout there is no finalPrice or SpecialPrice both are empty. I did that via getting the real product from item  id and then checked for special and final prices. How can I make it work via editing maybe the getCalculationPrice function instead of changing all?

Answer (score 0):

For getting normal price

```
$productPrice = $_item->getPrice();
```

For getting Special Price

```
$specialPrice = $_item->getFinalPrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like that.

discount: `$item->getDiscountAmount();`

original price: `$item->getCalculationPrice();`

Hope it will work